# Аналогия rez = num1 || num2 в php

Tags: php

В js можно записать так:

```
rez = num1 || num2;
```

И если `num1 = false/ null/ undefined` то `rez = num2`

А есть ли в `php` такое. Аналогичная запись не сработала.

И как вообще называется такая запись, подскажите, не могу нагуглить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начиная с версии **PHP 5.3** можно использовать тернарный оператор в таком варианте:

```
$var = $value ?: "Другое значение";
$var = $value ? $value : "Другое значение"; // Эквивалентно
```

> *Этот вариант полезно использовать, когда нужно изменить значение
>   переменной, только в случае, когда проверяемая переменная не равняется
>   `true`*

А начиная с версии **PHP 7.0** можно так:

```
$rez = $num1 ?? $num2;
$rez = isset($num1) ? $num1 : $num2; // Эквивалентно
```

[Источник.](http://php720.com/lesson/19)